# How to set proxy in ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to acess a webservice in a pl/sql code with 'utl_http' in a oracle 10.2 database but it is behind a proxy...How to set proxy in this case...there is a way to do this via proxy configuration or the server database needs to have direct acess to the address?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#ARPLS71100) for the procedure `SET_PROXY`. Seems straightforward enough.

Comment: Thanks HepC, that's it what I'm looking for!